# Why Isnt The Session Being Inserted Into Database?

Tags: php, mysql

Why can't I insert my session into my database? I'm sure I have used the same line of code elsewhere numerous times and it has worked for me till now.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['election'];
$vote = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['vote']);
$vote = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['vote']);

$sql= "INSERT INTO votes (election_id, ni) VALUES ('$id', '". $_SESSION['ni']."')";  

if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  else 
  {

      echo '<hr><h4>Your Vote Has Now Been Casted </h4><hr><h5> <a href = "votenow.php">My Account</a></h5>';

  }
?>
```

any ideas? the field ni comes out with the number 0

Comment: If that MySQL Error 1064 is the error you're receiving, maybe you should look into that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
session_start();
```

at the beginning of the file so the session variable will be set and initialized.

Comment: Did you start the session in the file that defines $_SESSION['ni']? Also, do you clean cookies in between or call session_destroy() ?

Comment: yes i did and i call session_destroy when a user wants to logout

Comment: It could help if you show us the code that sets the session variable maybe the problem is there? Have you tried printing the session variable 'ni' before the insert to make sure that it holds the right value? this will help us determine if the problem is with the session variable or with the DB transaction.

Comment: i have this same line of code on other pages in my website and the session is going through well. i have also printed the session variable 'ni' before the insert and it showed that it consisted the ni variable.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't comment on the previous answer due to low reputation... If var_dump($_SESSION['ni']) prints the right value and var_dump($sql) prints the query with null instead of the session then something happens between... do you have any lines of code between the two calls? I am referring to your comment where you said that it prints null.

Comment: nopeeee....i inserted the var_dump codes just after my opening php tag. what could possibly have gone wrong?

Comment: Could you please paste the entire code of the file with the var_dumps via pastebin or any other site?

Comment: `<?php
var_dump($sql);
exit;
$id = $_GET['election'];
$vote = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['vote']);
$vote = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['vote']);

$sql= "INSERT INTO votes (election_id, ni) VALUES ('$id', '". $_SESSION['ni']."')";  

if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
     die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  else 
  {
   
   echo '<hr><h4>Your Vote Has Now Been Casted </h4><hr><h5> <a href = "votenow.php">My Account</a></h5>';

  }
?>`

Comment: When you are doing the var_dump($sql) command on the beginning of the file the variable $sql is not defined. Please use the same command after the line "$sql = ...." and tell us the output of the var_dump.

Comment: `string(61) "INSERT INTO votes (election_id, ni) VALUES ('41', 'HP45896S')" `

Comment: That's weird... It looks OK... can you please try to run this query in MySQL it self or maybe PHPMyAdmin and see if you still get 0 in the row? Maybe there you will get an error or a warning of some sort. Also, what is the primary unique key in that table? if it's election_id, does a row with 41 already exists?

Comment: OH MY GOD! finally fixed my stupid problem! the field in my database was set to an int(8). no wonder nothing is going through...im sorry for wasting your time Odinn. thanks for your help, much appreciated

Comment: hehe... that happens, glad you fixed it, never would have thought of it because you said that in other files the same code works fine... oh well :)

Comment: lol yes i did say that but those codes were for other tables in my database. sorry once again :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with being a database specific issue, if before that code runs if you insert:

```
var_dump($_SESSION['ni']);
exit;
```

Does `$_SESSION['ni']` contain anything other than 0? Also have you called `session_start()` before you try and access the $_SESSION object?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: it gives me the following message: string(8) "HP45896S"

Comment: and if you do a `var_dump($sql)` after you define your $sql variable you don't see `HP45896S` in the generated SQL?

Comment: null, so there is no string what so ever in the $sql variable after you define it? would you be able to copy/paste the code snippet with the var_dump debug statement in it?